# What is the benefit in using 'unset'?

Tags: php, unset

The PHP manual says 'unset() destroys the specified variables.' It has the following example:

```
<?php
function destroy_foo() 
{
    global $foo;
    unset($foo);
}

$foo = 'bar';
destroy_foo();
echo $foo;
?>
```

The above code will output:

```
bar
```

So what has 'unset' done? Don't get it. Please explain.

Comment: global makes a local variable a reference to a variable in the global scope. When you unset inside the function, you're unsetting that reference, not the variable "above". `unset($GLOBALS['foo'])` would kill the value.

Comment: That should be added as an answer and accepted

Comment: @MarcB Please add your response as a Q, so I can accept. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

global makes a local variable a reference to a variable in the global scope. When you unset inside the function, you're unsetting that reference, not the variable "above".

e.g.

```
function foo() {
   global $bar;
   unset($bar);
}
```

is for the most part doing the same thing as

```
function foo() {
   $bar = &$GLOBALS['bar'];
   unset($bar); // kill the local reference, not the global variable.
}
```

it's just a bit easier on the eyes.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from Marc's comment, unset is often used in a variety of ways. Just one example -

Unset a certain item in an array:

```
$arr = array("a","b","c");
unset($arr['b']);
print_r($arr);

//gives us
//array("a","c");
```

Comment: Thank-you. Makes perfect sense now.